# How to switch from Hibernate to OpenJpa

Tags: java, spring, maven, persistence, openjpa

I've an Hibernate project developed with Spring MVC 3 and built with Maven 3. I manage persistence with JPA in particular Hibernate Framework; I guess that isn't so difficult to configure my existing source for OpenJpa, but I'm new to it and I'd like to know what are the steps to configure my project to switch in a consistent way from Hibernate to OpenJpa.

Greetings

Comment: I add some explanation and result of my searches:
- beans defined in Spring are the same, BUT the jpa vendor that becomes OpenJpa vendor
-I've to add OpenJpa plugin to my pom.xml
-I've to change persistence.xml file, but what and how?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

To switch to annotations, you’ll need to:

```
Add hibernate-annotations and JPA jars
Annotate your classes
Modify hibernate.cfg.xml to use classes instead of mapping files
Modify your HibernateUtil class to use a different configuration (this is the step that tripped me up)
```

To add the right jars, I’m using Maven and added the following additional dependencies:

```
<dependency>

  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>

  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>

  <version>1.0</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

  <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>

  <version>3.3.1.GA</version>

</dependency>
```

There are many fine resources available on JPA annotations so I’m not going to discuss this in detail. You’ll have something that looks like this:

```
@Entity

@Table(name = “USERS”)

public class User {

@Id @GeneratedValue

@Column(name = “USER_ID”)

private Long id;

@Column(name = “FIRST_NAME”)

private String firstName;

@Column(name = “LAST_NAME”)

private String lastName;

@Column(name = “EMAIL”)

private String email;

// etc

}
```

To update your hibernate.cfg.xml file, you’ll want to change lines like this:

```
<mapping resource="org/terracotta/reference/exam/domain/User.hbm.xml"/>
```

to something like this:

```
<mapping class="org.terracotta.reference.exam.domain.User">
```

If you did all that and stopped there, you might see an exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.terracotta.reference.exam.domain.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at org.terracotta.reference.exam.domain.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="org.terracotta.reference.exam.domain.User"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1600)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
    at org.terracotta.reference.exam.domain.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
```

And, like me, you would be puzzled. It turns out that when using annotations you need to use AnnotationConfiguration, which is a subclass of Configuration, specific to annotations. So, your HibernateUtil might look like this instead:

```
package org.terracotta.reference.exam.domain;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {

try {

sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

} catch(Throwable t) {

throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(t);

}

}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

return sessionFactory;

}

public static void shutdown() 
{

getSessionFactory().close();

}

}
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've two questions. I've never configured hibernate.cfg.xml, I haven't one in my project... is it really necessary to change Hibernate configuration to use a concurrent framework like OpenJpa?
  and do I've to execute all these steps in addition to steps I mentioned in the first comment?